# How to use excel to graph time points with proper spacing?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, charts

I'm trying to figure out which pool is more effective for mining Garlicoin, and I have some datapoints that I'm trying to graph to get an accurate line to represent the rate at which I receive GRLC.

There are 2 different pools. Pool A pays out every time you should receive at least .1 GRLC, and Pool B pays out for each block that is found by the pool.

Simply pasting the values into Excel and creating a simple line chart where each payout is evenly spaced doesn't give me an accurate picture of the rate, due to each time point being spaced evenly on the chart, instead of appearing at points that actually equate to the timestamp of the transaction.

Is there a different tool to use that is able to accomplish this, or am I possibly just overlooking a setting that would make the chart work like this? As far as I have found, the minimum time difference that Excel works with is 1 day, so if I have the X-axis formatted as a 'Date axis' type, it shows one step per day, evenly spaced. If I have the type as 'Text axis', it shows each point, but they are evenly spaced, instead of spaced according to the gap in time between the points, if that makes sense..

## Sample data

```
0.03367696,1/29/2018 21:12,0.03367696
0.01401613,1/29/2018 21:48,0.04769309
0.1018575,1/30/2018 19:53,0.14955059
0.10719082,1/31/2018 0:06,0.25674141
0.10007035,1/31/2018 4:11,0.35681176
0.1021725,1/31/2018 5:45,0.45898426
0.1035085,1/31/2018 6:57,0.56249276
0.10204597,1/31/2018 8:31,0.66453873
0.1010702,1/31/2018 10:05,0.76560893
0.10002185,1/31/2018 11:57,0.86563078
0.1016774,1/31/2018 13:23,0.96730818
0.10345239,1/31/2018 14:35,1.07076057
0.10074145,1/31/2018 15:42,1.17150202
0.10410395,1/31/2018 17:06,1.27560597
0.10087641,1/31/2018 18:37,1.37648238
0.10320091,1/31/2018 20:10,1.47968329
0.14972399,1/31/2018 20:55,1.62940728
0.1034838,1/31/2018 21:55,1.73289108
0.10368055,1/31/2018 23:25,1.83657163
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For time series data (especially with uneven intervals) I recommend using an XY/Scatter chart type.  Line charts create a horizontal axis using categorical intervals rather than ratio which creates even spacing between data points.

1. Convert your data into an Excel Data Table (always a good practice).
2. Ensure your date/time info is recognized by Excel as date/time data (it will vary by region, but if you change the date/time formatting to number, you should get a result of approximately 43129.88 for 2018-01-29 21:12).
3. Add a blank XY/Scatter Chart.
4. Add your data, using your date/time column for horizontal axis and your pools for each series.
5. Format to taste.

[image]